# Why does my function execute remaining code after encountering a return (return inside of two loops)

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement, return

I don't understand why this function will run the remaining code after the return statement is supposed to be called:

```
function func(i) {
while (i >= 0) {
if (i < 0) {    
    return;
    }    
    document.write("inside loop, i is  " + i);
    document.write("</br>");

i--;
} //end of while 
document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
document.write("</br>");
}
func(2);
```

Output:

```
inside loop, i is 2; 
inside loop, i is 1; 
inside loop, i is 0; 
end of function, i is -1;
```

I was expecting:

```
inside loop, i is 2; 
inside loop, i is 1; 
inside loop, i is 0;
```

1. Why is the line "end of function, i is -1" being written if the return should be called before it?
2. If I replace while(i >= 0) with while(true) the function gives the expected output (without the last document.write). Why is that?
3. If I replace the code after the while loop with:

   ```
   return document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
   document.write("end 2 of function, i is " + i);
   ```

the last code line (end 2 of function, i is ) is not executed. Why does the code keep executing after the first return and not after the second?

4. If I take the return out of the if statement the function stops when return is called:

   ```
   while (i >= 0) { 
     document.write("inside loop, i is  " + i);
     document.write("</br>");
     i--;
     return; 
   }
   ```

output is:

```
inside loop, i is 2
```

Why doesn't the last document.write ("end of function, i is ") execute in this case?

Comment: the return condition `if (i < 0)` will never be hit since the while condition is `while i >= 0`. Return statement is never hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` condition:

```
while (i >= 0) {
```

will *never* be true at the same time that the `return` test is true:

```
if (i < 0) {    
  return;
}
```

Since `i` doesn't get changed between the top of the `while` loop and the `i < 0` test, the `if` will never be fulfilled. On the last iteration, `i` will be decremented from 0 to -1 just before the end of the `while` block, and since an `i` of `-1` fails the `while` test, no further iterations will run (and the `if` check and `return` will not be encountered).

If you had the `while` loop continue indefinitely, until the `if` statement was fulfiled, the function would indeed return:

```js
function func(i) {
  while (true) {
    if (i < 0) {
      return;
    }
    document.write("inside loop, i is  " + i);
    document.write("</br>");

    i--;
  } //end of while 
  document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
  document.write("</br>");
}
func(2);
```

As for

> 3. If after the while loop I replace the code with:
>
>    ```
>    return document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
>    document.write("end 2 of function, i is " + i);
>    ```

and

> 4. If I take the return out of the if statement the function stops when return is called:
>
>    ```
>    while (i >= 0) { 
>    ...
>    return;
>    ```

In both of these cases, the `return` statement *is* actually being encountered, so the function terminates there as expected. (In your original code, the interpreter never runs across the `return`, because the `if` is never fulfilled)

Comment: You are right! I don't know why I didn't see it. I is so simple!

Answer (score -1):

Use break; instead or better still use return false; like so

```
function func(i) {
while (true) {
if (i < 0) {    
    break;
    }    
    document.write("inside loop, i is  " + i);
    document.write("</br>");

i--;
} //end of while 
document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
document.write("</br>");
}
func(2);
```

OR

```
function func(i) {
while (true) {
if (i < 0) {    
    return false;
    }    
    document.write("inside loop, i is  " + i);
    document.write("</br>");

i--;
} //end of while 
document.write("end of function, i is " + i);
document.write("</br>");
}
func(2);
```

I don't know about the second (return false) but the first should do the trick.
I hope it helps.